# Can I do this? $("msgcntDiv").data("newMessageCnt.php");

Tags: jquery

I have a variable in a span tag:

```
 echo "<span class='headings_sub' id='msgcntDiv'>You have ".$numOfMessages." </span>";
```

My script:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         var reload = function(){  
       $("msgcntDiv").load("newMessageCnt.php");
    }
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $("#msgcntDiv").load(reload);
    }, 10000);
     });   
</script>
```

"newMessageCnt.php" has one line:

```
<?php
include('header_application.php');
$pageValue = "dashboard";
$obj_clean->check_user();
echo $numOfMessages = $obj_clean->getUnopenedMessagesCount($_SESSION['user_id']);    
?>
```

Comment: I thin you must use `load('...');` instead of `.data(...)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for $.load, and not $.data. Also, you may want to call it in interval or repeatable timeout:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var reload = function(){
       $("msgcntDiv").load("newMessageCnt.php"); 
    }
    window.setInterval(reload, 10000);

 });   
</script>
```

Comment: You mean $("msgcntDiv").load() ;)

Comment: yeah, copy paste, and forgot to edit since my cellphone was ringing. Thanks :)

Comment: Wouldn't using `setTimeout` recursively be a bit safer in this case? Suppose something went wrong on the server, it would prevent to keep on making requests. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval/731625#731625

Comment: thanks all i have the  $("msgcntDiv").load("newMessageCnt.php"); as:
     $("msgcntDiv").load(<?php $obj_clean->getUnopenedMessagesCount($_SESSION['user_id']); ?>);

can i do this? other wise my .php will only have one line in it though

Comment: @Helloise Smit You can't, as the PHP will be executed just one, to render the javascript. You need to call PHP file in order to get the new data.

Comment: Helloise, you seem to be mixing JS and PHP there. My suggestion would be to keep newMessageCnt.php as a separate service that returns the count you need.

Comment: thank you all i changed it back but it is not updating my variable $numOfMessages in the span??

Comment: @Helloise Smit that means you have fatal error in your PHP, but display_errors is off. Turn on display errors, or at least show the code. By the way, your PHP should not be one line long, as you have to initialize $obj_clean

Comment: all ok now thank you but  it is not updating my variable $numOfMessages in the span?? please see my code for newMessageCnt.php at the top

Comment: You need to echo the $numOfMessages variable from your script.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        refresh();
    });

    function refresh()
    {
        $.get('getUnopenedMessage.php', function (cnt) {
            // $("#msgcntDiv").data('cnt', cnt);
            $("#msgcntDiv span").text(cnt);
            setTimeout(refresh(), 10000);               
        });
    }
</script>
```

and file getUnopenedMessage.php, more or less:

```
<?php 
//session_start();
$obj_clean = new yourMailClass('...');
echo $obj_clean->getUnopenedMessagesCount($_SESSION['user_id']) 
?>
```

Comment: probably setTimeout(refresh, 10000); ?

Comment: it does call my .php but nope its not updating my variable in the <span>

Comment: does `$("#msgcntDiv").text(cnt);` do the trick? $.data() is a jquery function to set and get "private attributes" to dom elements of your choosing. I thougt you had another jquery function reading this cnt data in order to display the number of new mails. @Darhazer: yes! thanx! edited! ^^